# Choose randomly between two variables and give one of them the value true

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a game where the code will randomly choose one box/button of two and give it the value ***true***. If you click on the right box/button you win.
But I don't know how to do it.

I've looked around but I haven't found anything helpful.

The HTML

```
    <button id="button1">1</button>
    <button id="button2">2</button>
```

The JS

```
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1')
var button2 = document. getElementById('button2')
var array = [('button1'), ('button2')];
```

The CSS

```
#button1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    color: blue;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 290px;}
#button2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    color: blue;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 290px;}
```

I just want someone to tell me what to do to make the random choosing step, 
thank you.

Comment: Since it's hidden you could just print 'You win' (and disable the buttons) 50% of the time and the user experience is identical :)

Answer (score 1):

You could enable or disble the button randomly.

```js
setInterval(function () {
    var random = Math.round(Math.random());
    ['button1', 'button2'].forEach((id, i) => document.getElementById(id).disabled = i === random);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button id="button1">1</button>
<button id="button2">2</button>
```

Comment: This works for the original question, but I don't think it would if the array was longer than 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.random()`

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1')
var button2 = document. getElementById('button2')
var array = [('button1'), ('button2')];
var winItem = 1;

function getRandomItemNum(length) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * length)
}

function recalculateWinItem() {
  winItem = getRandomItemNum(array.length);
}

function checkIsWin(buttonNum) {
  console.log(`Clicked ${buttonNum}. Win item: ${winItem}`);
  console.log(buttonNum === winItem ? "You won" : "You lose");
}

recalculateWinItem();
```

```html
    <button id="button1" onclick="checkIsWin(1)">1</button>
    <button id="button2" onclick="checkIsWin(2)">2</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't write "You won" or "You lose".

Comment: @Elguti run code snippet in StackOverflow. It works.